# mpl-token-metadata 4.1.2 causing issues

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, mpl-token-metadata

I have been working to update this code to solana 1.18.8, anchor 0.29.0, and mpl-token-metadata 4.1.2.

I have repaired most of the issues except 3.

I have tried importing create_metadata_account_v3 and create_master_edition_v3 like you could under anchor_spl::Metadata, but under mpl_token_metadata::instructions in numerous different ways and I am getting errors that it is private even though the .rs file has it pub.

Additionally, my #[derive(Accounts)] is being hijacked by mpl-token-metadata::Accounts rather than associating with use anchor_lang::prelude::*; as it should.

I am including my code, however, I am aware that there are weird use statements based on my multiple attempts to fix the private issue.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    token::{mint_to, Mint, MintTo, Token, TokenAccount},
};
use mpl_token_metadata::{
    instructions::{CreateMetadataAccountV3CpiAccounts, create_metadata_account_v3, CreateMasterEditionV3, create_master_edition_v3},
    types::DataV2,
    accounts::{MasterEdition, Metadata},
};
declare_id!("");
 
    #[program]
    pub mod solana_nft_anchor {

        use super::*;
    
        pub fn init_nft(
            ctx: Context<InitNFT>,
            name: String,
            symbol: String,
            uri: String,
        ) -> Result<()> {
    
            // create mint account
            let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                MintTo {
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.associated_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                },
            );
    
            mint_to(cpi_context, 1)?;

        // Create metadata account
        let data_v2 = DataV2 {
            name,
            symbol,
            uri,
            seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
            creators: None,
            collection: None,
            uses: None,
        };
        let metadata_account_pubkey = *ctx.accounts.metadata_account.key;
        let mint_pubkey = *ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().key;
        let mint_authority_pubkey = *ctx.accounts.signer.key;
        let payer_pubkey = *ctx.accounts.signer.key;
        let update_authority_pubkey = *ctx.accounts.signer.key;
        let system_program_pubkey = *ctx.accounts.system_program.key;
        let rent_pubkey = Some(*ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info().key);

        let cpi_accounts = CreateMetadataAccountV3CpiAccounts {
            metadata: &ctx.accounts.metadata_account.to_account_info(),
            mint: &ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            mint_authority: &ctx.accounts.signer,
            payer: &ctx.accounts.signer,
            update_authority: (&ctx.accounts.signer, true),
            system_program: &ctx.accounts.system_program,
            rent: Some(&ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info()),
        };

        let cpi_ctx = ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info();

        // Invoke CPI for creating metadata account
        create_metadata_account_v3(cpi_ctx, None)?;

        let edition_pubkey = *ctx.accounts.master_edition_account.key;
        let token_program_pubkey = *ctx.accounts.token_program.key;
        // Create master edition account
        let cpi_accounts = CreateMasterEditionV3 {
            edition: edition_pubkey,
            mint: mint_pubkey,
            update_authority: update_authority_pubkey,
            mint_authority: mint_authority_pubkey,
            payer: payer_pubkey,
            metadata: metadata_account_pubkey,
            token_program: token_program_pubkey,
            system_program: system_program_pubkey,
            rent: rent_pubkey,
        };

        let cpi_ctx = ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info().clone();

        // Invoke CPI for creating master edition account
        create_master_edition_v3(cpi_ctx, None)?;

        Ok(())
    }

    #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct InitNFT<'info> {
        #[account(mut, signer)]
        pub signer: AccountInfo<'info>,
        #[account(
            init,
            payer = signer,
            mint::decimals = 0,
            mint::authority = signer,
            mint::freeze_authority = signer
        )]
        pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
        #[account(
            init_if_needed,
            payer = signer,
            associated_token::mint = mint,
            associated_token::authority = signer
        )]
        pub associated_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
        #[account(mut, address = Metadata::find_pda(&mint.key()).0)]
        pub metadata_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
        #[account(mut, address = MasterEdition::find_pda(&mint.key()).0)]
        pub master_edition_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
        pub update_authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
        pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
        pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
        pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
        pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
        pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    }
}
```

I am new to Solana so any help would be appreciated.